# Deleting one band from raster file?

Tags: qgis, raster

I was working using drone imagery (regular camera) and there is this alpha band which is preventing me from doing maximum likelihood classification.

I want to remove the alpha band. So far I used raster calculator, separate the image into 3 images for each band (R, G, B) and them using raster merge to join them again, but this is so time-consuming and circuitous.

Is there any simpler way?

Comment: Not related to your question but  I suspect you are you using Photoscan or Metashape to process your imagery?  If so, when you export your orthomosaic be sure to uncheck 'Write alpha channel' to prevent this from happening in the future.

Answer (score 19):

If you know how to access **gdal** from the OSGeo4W command line shell which comes with QGIS, you could try [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) to export the first 3 bands:

```
gdal_translate -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 input.tif output.tif
```

Comment: How can I do this with R?

Comment: ´gdalUtils::gdalwarp(srcfile, ....)´ or ´gdalUtilities::gdalwarp( ... )´